# Как написать Linq запрос к коллекции, где значение коллекции- свой класс?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть коллекция `Dictionary<string, MyClass> products = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();` Одно из свойств класса `MyClass` - `Group` (группа товара), тип `string`. Мне нужно узнать есть хоть один элемент в коллекции, у которого свойство `Group = "Мясо"`, к примеру.

```
if (products.Where(x=>x.Value?.Group == "Мясо").Count()>0)
```

Так корректно? Спасибо. Мне важно, чтобы максимально быстро была проверка

Comment: забыли `ToList`, а так все должно работать.

Comment: Вместо `.Where(x=>x.Value?.Group == "Мясо").Count()>0` проще написать `Any(x=>x.Value?.Group == "Мясо")`

Comment: В любом случае linq будет уступать в производительности обычному перебору с помощью цикла. К тому же у вас запрос будет осуществлять проход от первого до последнего элемента, хотя правильнее было бы останавливаться, когда хотя бы один найден.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, не в любом.

Comment: @Grundy можете привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko чушь полная. Обычный цикл внутри использует те же самые итераторы что и linq. Они ничем не отличаются в производительности. Ну разве что брать в рассчет чисто теоретические расходы на вызов калбэков, но они просто микроскопические, да и то скорее всего оптимизатором развернутся в обычный цикл.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК понятное дело, что разница будет мизерной, но все же она есть. Иногда время выполнения будет одинаковой, но вот чтобы linq быстрее был в каких-то случаях - для меня это что-то новенькое.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko кто сказал что он быстрее? Просто одинаково. Не забывайте что с циклами придется заводить дополнительные переменные, а то и создавать промежуточные массивы. И вся эта надуманная оптимизация от отсутствия калбэков пойдет прахом. Так что да - может даже и быстрее. Я уж молчу что linq намного читабельнее (для того он и придуман).

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, я немного перепутал с разницей `for` и `foreach`. Однако, например определение наличия пересечения двух коллекций с помощью `.Intersect().Any()` быстрее наивной реализации с двумя вложенными циклами.

Comment: @Grundy ну конечно, ведь там используется множество для нахождения пересечения. В обычном цикле тоже можно использовать множества) Ваша идея понятна

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, ну и стоит отметить, что от данных тоже может зависеть все.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Linq - это абстракция, она не может быть быстрее или медленнее конкретной реализации с циклом. Если же говорить о Linq to Objects, то надо рассматривать конкретные примеры. Например, если вы напишете метод-фильтрацию на цикле, и запустите его дважды/трижды/и тд (например, отфильтровать по дате, потом по возрасту, потом по фазе луны и тд), то с циклами вы получите несколько проходов по коллекции, с Linq to Objects - только один проход, что вроде как быстрее.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ну и надо иметь ввиду затраты по памяти. Когда вы фильтруете циклом, вы можете либо создать новую коллекцию как результат или придется менять старую. Linq to obj же помогает пройти по фильтрованному результату без изменения исходной коллекции и без особых трат по памяти

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответ и познавательный батл между Linq и foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чуть подробнее поясню ответ, который вам дали в комментариях.

Ваш запрос неоптимален. У вас сначала отбираются элементы через Where, потом считается их число. И только потом проверяется на ноль.

Представьте, что вы решили сделать эту проверку перебором. При этом вы сначала отобрали элементы с "мясо" в новую переменную (заняли память, съели время). Потом другим циклом посчитали количество элементов и записали в переменную (заняли память, сделали второй проход по циклу) и потом сравнили.

Вы же так не стали бы делать, верно? Вот и мы давайте не будем делать.

Можно объединить Where и Count:

```
if (products.Count(x=>x.Value?.Group == "Мясо")>0)
```

Уже стало лучше. Однако стоит ли перебирать весь массив или достаточно найти хотя бы один элемент и как только нашли - сразу выйти из цикла?

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (source));
  if (predicate == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (predicate));
  foreach (TSource source1 in source)
  {
    if (predicate(source1))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Заменяем Count на Any:

```
if (products.Any(x=>x.Value?.Group == "Мясо"))
```

Всё, в пределах linq больше оптимизировать некуда.

Отдельное замечание нужно сделать по поводу того, что могла бы первая оптимизация сделана самим компилятором при условии, что у вас был бы IQueryable, а не IEnumerable, но я не уверен, что компилятор бы смог заменить Count > 0 на Any - он бы честно посчитал.

Стоит ли заменять linq на цикл? Не стоит - я показал, что под капотом у Any тот же самый цикл. А выглядит такая linq конструкция короче и семантичнее, а потому понятнее при чтении.

Comment: _У вас сначала отбираются элементы через Where, потом считается их число._ ну не, это ж не так работает тут же итераторы

Comment: @Grundy Это правда, но есть два "но", оба учебно-педагогического характера. Во-первых, задающие подобного рода вопросы не держат решарпер, который предложил бы упростить код. Поэтому когда-нибудь доберутся и увидят эти рефакторинги - поймут о чём была речь. Во-вторых, мне так нагляднее пояснить мысль про два цикла и показать на этом наглядном примере ненужность.

Comment: Но фактически проход по массиву будет один